# Goldbach conjecture solution finder

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, primes

The Goldbach conjecture says: **any even number greater than two can be represented by the sum of two prime numbers.**

> G(n) = { (p1, p2) | p1 + p2 = n, p1 and p2 are prime numbers with p1 < p2 }

For example:

> G(6) = **{(3, 3)}**
>
> G(12) = **{(5, 7)}**
>
> G(26) = **{(3, 23),(7, 19),(13, 13)}**

So I have to do an algorithm that determines which three numbers n1, n2 and n3 are between **1,000,000** and **2,000,000** for which the
**G (n1)**, **G (n2)** and **G (n3)** have the largest number of elements.

I do not know if I need to improve something in my code, or even optimize some part that is poorly written. It currently taking about 12 seconds.

```
public class Goldbach  {

    private static int j;
    private static int k;
    private static int [] primes;
    private static int [] just_primes;
    private static int [] conjunct;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 

        primes = new int[2000000];
        for ( int i=0; i<2000000; i++ ) {
            primes[i] = i+1;
        }

        for ( int i=1; i<1000000; i++ ) {
            if ( primes[i] != 0 ) {
                j = primes[i];
                k = j;
                while ( k <= 2000000 ) {
                    k += j;
                    if ( k <= 2000000 ) {
                        primes[ k-1 ] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        just_primes = new int [primes.length];
        for ( int i = 0; i< primes.length-1 ; i++ ) {
            just_primes[i] = 0;
        }

        k = 0;
        for ( int i = 1; i< primes.length-1 ; i++ ) {
            if ( primes[i] > 0 ) {
                just_primes[k] = primes[i];
                k++;
            }
        }

        conjunct = new int[1000001];
        for ( int i = 0; i<1000001 ; i++ ) {
            conjunct[i] = 0;
        }

        int p;
        for ( int i = 0; i< k ; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = i; j< k ; j++ ) {
                int w = just_primes[i]+just_primes[j];
                if ( w >= 1000000 && w <= 2000000 ) {
                    p = w - 1000000;
                    conjunct[p]++;
                }
            }
        }

        int big1 = 0;
        int big2 = 0;
        int big3 = 0;
        int n1 = 0;
        int n2 = 0;
        int n3 = 0;

        for ( int i = 0; i<1000001 ; i++ ) {
            if ( conjunct[i] >= big1 ) {
                big3 = big2;
                big2 = big1;
                big1 = conjunct[i];
                n3 = n2;
                n2 = n1;
                n1 = i;
            } else {
                if ( conjunct[i] >= big2 ) {
                    big3 = big2;
                    big2 = conjunct[i];
                    n3 = n2;
                    n2 = i;
                } else {
                    if ( conjunct[i] >= big3 ) {
                        big3 = conjunct[i];
                        n3 = i;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }


        System.out.println( "Largest conjunct 1: " + n1 + " " + 1000000+big1 + " pairs" );
        System.out.println( "Largest conjunct 2: " + n2 + " " + 1000000+big2 + " pairs" );
        System.out.println( "Largest conjunct 3: " + n3 + " " + 1000000+big3 + " pairs" );

    }

}
```

Expected result:

```
Largest conjunct 1: 981980 100000027988 pairs
Largest conjunct 2: 951950 100000027802 pairs
Largest conjunct 3: 995630 100000027730 pairs
```

Comment: How are 981980, 951950, and 995630 "between 1,000,000 and 2,000,000"?

Comment: Good point, he needs to add 10^6 to the number first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it looks pretty good. One possible way to make it faster is in this part:

```
for ( int i = 0; i< k ; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = i; j< k ; j++ ) {
        int w = just_primes[i]+just_primes[j];
        if ( w >= 1000000 && w <= 2000000 ) {
            p = w - 1000000;
            conjunct[p]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that for each value of justprimes[i] you are currently testing all values of justprimes[j] and after this you are testing if the sum is in the desired interval.

One way to work around this is by using a two pointer method that tells us the biggest possible value j can take for any value of i, and also by breaking out of the loop as soon as j becomes to small.

```
int high = k-1;
    for ( int i = 0; i< k ; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = high; j>=i ; j-- ) {
            int w = just_primes[i]+just_primes[j];
            if(w< 1000000) break;
            if ( w <= 2000000 ) {
                p = w - 1000000;
                conjunct[p]++;
            }
            else{
                while( just_primes[i]+ just_primes[high] > 2000000 && high > 0){
                    high --;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This seems to give a 15% speed boost in my computer.