# Given a list of numbers and a number, return whether any two numbers from the list add up to

Tags: python

For example, given `[10, 15, 3, 7]` and a number `k` of `17`, return `True` since `10 + 7` is `17`.

How can I improve the below solution?

```
from itertools import combinations

def add_up_to(numbers, k):

 c_k_2 = list(combinations(numbers, 2))

 return any([True for pair in c_k_2 if sum(pair) == k])
```

Comment: consider sorting and using two pointers for quick performance

Comment: @HereToRelax Consider writing an answer and providing some more explanation for contributors that are looking to learn and improve

Comment: I have an answer on two pointers here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/219139/62030

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I implemented your proposed approach (my interpretation of course, as there's not a lot of information provided), sorted the list and used two pointers to run across the array. I used a numpy array to get good sorting performance. While there was a sweet spot (list length around 1.000) where this approach slightly outperformed my proposed algortihm using a `set`, it was significantly slower for long lists. If you actually know of a faster approach, I'd be interested to learn, so please do share!

Comment: How do you get a list of 10^10 elements and how long does it take once the list is loaded?

Comment: it takes me considerably longer to generate a suitable list or read one for the sizes that fit on my ram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can take your approach even further than riskypenguin did by pushing the work pretty much entirely into C-code:

```
def add_up_to(numbers, k):
    return k in map(sum, combinations(numbers, 2))
```

Takes \$O(1)\$ space instead of your \$O(n^2)\$, and best case time is \$O(1)\$ instead of your \$O(n^2)\$. And it's nice and short. Plus the C code is faster.

Benchmark with a worst case, `numbers, k = [0] * 1000, 1`:

```
546.63 ms  original
386.11 ms  riskypenguin
229.90 ms  Manuel
```

Benchmark with a "best case", `numbers, k = [0] * 1000, 1`:

```
594.35 ms  original
  0.02 ms  riskypenguin
  0.02 ms  Manuel
```

Why did I put quotes around "best case"? Because for you it's a worst case. Note your increased time. You treat all pairs in any case, and you do the most work when they all have the desired sum: then you build the longest possible list, full of `True` values. The other solutions see the first pair and right away stop, hence their tiny times.

Those are of course all [moo points](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62necDwQb5E), as this problem should be solved in \$O(n)\$ time (as riskypenguin did later) or at most \$O(n \log n)\$ time. Unless you're only allowed \$O(1)\$ space and forbidden to modify the given list, which is rather unrealistic.

Benchmark code:

```
from timeit import repeat
from functools import partial
from itertools import combinations

def original(numbers, k):
    c_k_2 = list(combinations(numbers, 2))
    return any([True for pair in c_k_2 if sum(pair) == k])

def riskypenguin(numbers, k):
    return any(sum(pair) == k for pair in combinations(numbers, 2))

def Manuel(numbers, k):
    return k in map(sum, combinations(numbers, 2))

def benchmark(numbers, k, reps):
    print(f'{len(numbers)=} {k=} {reps=}')
    funcs = original, riskypenguin, Manuel
    for _ in range(3):
        for func in funcs:
            t = min(repeat(partial(func, numbers, k), number=reps))
            print('%6.2f ms ' % (t * 1e3), func.__name__)
        print()

# benchmark([10, 15, 3, 7], 17, 10**5)
benchmark([0] * 1000, 1, 5)
benchmark([0] * 1000, 0, 5)
```

Comment: That's a really clean solution compared to my first version, +1! Could you include my proposed approach using a `set` in your benchmarks? I would hope it performs pretty well, especially in worst case scenarios

Comment: @riskypenguin Hmm, I left it out intentionally, as I don't find it interesting to confirm the obvious :-P. I really just wanted to compare the `combinations`+`sum` versions, didn't even include another O(1) space non-modifying solution of mine that's about four times faster. But I ran your set solution now, takes about 0.4 to 0.5 ms for that "worst case", although that's not quite fair as it additionally unrealistically benefits from its set remaining a single element.

Comment: I see your point, no worries. Do you have an idea where your performance improvement comes from exactly? Is it just the replacement of `==` by `in` or the presumably reduced overhead of not calling `any`? Or does `map` simply outperform user-written generator expressions?

Comment: @riskypenguin I think it's the `map` vs the generator expression. With the latter, you're still interpreting Python code all the time. And maybe all the "context switches" between `any` and the generator also hurt. I'm kinda disappointed the speed difference isn't bigger :-)

Comment: @TobySpeight Bah, [that was intentional](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62necDwQb5E) :-(

Comment: "Bah" - or "Baa"?  ;-)

Comment: I tried to edit it myself, but turns out there's a minimum number of characters you can edit; the best case scenario should have `k == 0`, not `k == 1`, there's a typo in the benchmark example!

Answer (score 9):

---

**Indents**

[PEP 8: *Use 4 spaces per indentation level.*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

---

**`True if condition else False`**

The pattern `True if condition else False` can be replaced by `condition` if it evaluates to a `bool`. If you are checking for [truthy and falsey values](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/) you can replace the pattern by `bool(condition)`.

While this lets us simplify the `return` statement

```
return any([sum(pair) == k for pair in c_k_2])
```

it actually performs worse (as pointed out by Manuel in the comments) without implementing further improvements (see the next point). While you originally create a list of only `True` values, this simplification will create a list that also includes all the `False` values, which we do not need at all.

---

**Drop the `list`**

You convert to a list twice in your code, once explicitly by calling the `list(...)` constructor and once implicitly by wrapping a generator expression with `[...]`. In your particular use case, both are unnecessary.

When dropping the call to the `list` constructor, `combinations(numbers, 2)` will provide an `itertools.combinations` object, which I would assume behaves similiarly to a generator, which is a lazily evaluated iterable. This way we don't compute and store all possible combinations of numbers in advance, which is perfect for us because we

1. only need one pair of numbers at a time
2. want to stop evaluating the expression once we find a pair that matches our criteria

Dropping the brackets `[]` around our generator expression follows the same logic.

[Generator expressions vs. list comprehensions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehensions)

---

Applying these improvements will make the code more efficient, more readable and more concise:

```
def any_two_elements_add_up_to(numbers, k):
    pairs = combinations(numbers, 2)
    return any(sum(pair) == k for pair in pairs)

# or as a one-liner

def any_two_elements_add_up_to(numbers, k):
    return any(sum(pair) == k for pair in combinations(numbers, 2))
```

---

**EDIT: Algorithm**

I've tried my hand at a faster approach, this is the first solution I came up with. Although it's really simple it still outperforms the above solution by orders of magnitude as it runs in O(n).

Here's the code:

```
def new_approach(numbers, target):
    counterparts = set()

    for num in numbers:
        if num in counterparts:
            return True

        counterparts.add(target - num)

    return False
```

Since every number only has one counterpart `k - x` that would make it add up to `k`, we can keep a `set` of all possible counterparts that we've identified so far. Once we come across a number that is in our `set` of counterparts (i.e. adds up to `k` with a previous number) we return `True`. If we don't come across one such number, we simply return `False`.

Comment: They don't have the pattern `True if condition else False`, though, and that first simplification of yours actually makes the code slower when there are a lot of `False` values that then get added to the list (for example in my answer's "worst case" input). You also make it sound too general, for example if `condition` is a string, then it doesn't evaluate to `True` or `False`, so it's not equivalent to the `True if condition else False` pattern.

Comment: Very good points, thank you! I will update my answer accordingly